# GraphQL Query Not Returning Anything From Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, graphql

I'm using the laravel-graphql library from Folklore. I've followed all the instructions to the T, but when I test it out in the Altair Client for Windows, I get "Unknown Server Error, Code 0". My REST API works so it's either that I made an error in setting up the GraphQL layer or Folklore not updating their library has finally fallen behind to the Laravel version that I'm using. It's 5.7.

**POSTTYPE.PHP**

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Type;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Folklore\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

/* Here we're giving the type a name and description */
class PostType extends GraphQLType {
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Post', //here we're defining the query by giving it a name of Post
        'description' => 'One post'
    ];

    public function fields(){
        return [
            'id' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
                'description' => 'Primary key; incrementing id of post'
            ],
            'header' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The header of the post'
            ],
            'body' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The body of the blog post'
            ],
            'created_at' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'When the post was created'
            ],
            'updated_at' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'When the post was last updated'
            ],
            'img' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'Where the main image of the blog post is stored'
            ],
        ];
    }

    // If you want to resolve the field yourself, you can declare a method
    // with the following format resolve[FIELD_NAME]Field()

    //protected function resolveEmailField($root, $args)
    //{
    //    return strtolower($root->email);
    //}
}
```

**POSTQUERY.PHP**

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Query;

use GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Folklore\GraphQL\Support\Query;
use App\Post;

class PostsQuery extends Query {
    //give the query a name of 'posts'
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'posts' 
    ];

    //define the query type
    public function type(){
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('Post'));
    }

    //define things to fetch and turn them into arguments
    public function args(){
        return [
            'id' => ['name' => 'id', 'type' => Type::int()],
            'header' => ['name' => 'header', 'type' => Type::string()],
            'body' => ['name' => 'body', 'type' => Type::string()],
            'img' => ['name' => 'img', 'type' => Type::string()],
        ];
    }

    //fetch all the posts
    public function resolve($root, $args){
        if (isset($args['id'])){
            return Post::where('id', $args['id'])->get();
        }
        else if (isset($args['header'])){
            return Post::where('header', $args['header'])->get();
        }
        else if (isset($args['body'])){
            return Post::where('body', $args['body'])->get();
        }
        else if (isset($args['img'])){
            return Post::where('img', $args['img'])->get();
        }
        else {
            return Post::all();
        }
    }
}
```

**CONFIG/GRAPHQL.PHP**

```
<?php


return [

    // The prefix for routes
    'prefix' => 'graphql',

    // The routes to make GraphQL request. Either a string that will apply
    // to both query and mutation or an array containing the key 'query' and/or
    // 'mutation' with the according Route
    //
    // Example:
    //
    // Same route for both query and mutation
    //
    // 'routes' => 'path/to/query/{graphql_schema?}',
    //
    // or define each routes
    //
    // 'routes' => [
    //     'query' => 'query/{graphql_schema?}',
    //     'mutation' => 'mutation/{graphql_schema?}'
    // ]
    //
    // you can also disable routes by setting routes to null
    //
    // 'routes' => null,
    //
    'routes' => '{graphql_schema?}',

    // The controller to use in GraphQL request. Either a string that will apply
    // to both query and mutation or an array containing the key 'query' and/or
    // 'mutation' with the according Controller and method
    //
    // Example:
    //
    // 'controllers' => [
    //     'query' => '\Folklore\GraphQL\GraphQLController@query',
    //     'mutation' => '\Folklore\GraphQL\GraphQLController@mutation'
    // ]
    //
    'controllers' => '\Folklore\GraphQL\GraphQLController@query',

    // Any middleware for the graphql route group
    'middleware' => [],

    // The name of the default schema used when no argument is provided
    // to GraphQL::schema() or when the route is used without the graphql_schema
    // parameter.
    'schema' => 'default',

    // The schemas for query and/or mutation. It expects an array to provide
    // both the 'query' fields and the 'mutation' fields. You can also
    // provide directly an object GraphQL\Schema
    //
    // Example:
    //
    // 'schemas' => [
    //     'default' => new Schema($config)
    // ]
    //
    // or
    //
    // 'schemas' => [
    //     'default' => [
    //         'query' => [
    //              'users' => 'App\GraphQL\Query\UsersQuery'
    //          ],
    //          'mutation' => [
    //
    //          ]
    //     ]
    // ]
    //
    'schemas' => [
        'default' => [
            'query' => [
                'posts' => 'App\GraphQL\Query\PostsQuery'
            ],
            'mutation' => [
                'newPost' => 'App\GraphQL\Mutation\NewPostMutation',
                //'updatePostStatus' => App\GraphQL\Mutation\UpdatePostStatusMutation::class,
            ]
        ]
    ],

    // The types available in the application. You can then access it from the
    // facade like this: GraphQL::type('user')
    //
    // Example:
    //
    // 'types' => [
    //     'user' => 'App\GraphQL\Type\UserType'
    // ]
    //
    // or whitout specifying a key (it will use the ->name property of your type)
    //
    'types' => [
        'App\GraphQL\Type\PostType',
    ],
    //
    //'types' => [
    //    'Post' => 'App\GraphQL\Type\PostType',
    //],

    // This callable will receive every Error object for each error GraphQL catches.
    // The method should return an array representing the error.
    //
    // Typically:
    // [
    //     'message' => '',
    //     'locations' => []
    // ]
    //
    'error_formatter' => ['\Folklore\GraphQL\GraphQL', 'formatError']

];
```

### -

-

**UPDATE**
So I installed the Rebing library and uninstalled the Folklore one, and got GraphiQL to work. I ran a query in it and got

```js
"message": "Class App\\GraphQL\\Type\\UserType does not exist",
  "exception": "ReflectionException",
  "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\laravel-project\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php",
  "line": 779,
```

Something tells me I'm not supposed to be seeing paths like this. If this is wrong, how do I fix?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so apparently the Rebing Laravel-GraphQL library (maybe the Folklore one too) handles cache poorly. I had to clear Laravel config cache every time I made a change. So if anyone gets into this problem, ensure you get GraphiQL working and clear your config for each change you make. Nothing is wrong with the double slashes. Apparently it's a UNIX thing. I've never seen that before (or never seen that in a bad error) so forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

In your config/graphql instead of `'posts' => 'App\GraphQL\Query\PostsQuery'`
use `'posts' => App\GraphQL\Query\PostsQuery::class`.
It depends on version of PHP sometimes.